# Why can not I update?

Tags: updates, software-sources

I run `lsb_release -a`

Output:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS
Release:    12.04
Codename:   precise
```

I run:   `nano /etc/apt/sources.list`

Output:

```
deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt precise main universe
deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt precise main-updates universe multiverse
deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt precise main-backports universe multiverse
deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt precise main-security universe multiverse
```

I run `sudo apt-get update`

Outuput:

```
Hit http://ftp.oleane.net/ubuntu/ precise Release.gpg
Hit http://ftp.oleane.net/ubuntu/ precise Release
Hit http://ftp.oleane.net/ubuntu/ precise/main i386 Packages
Hit http://ftp.oleane.net/ubuntu/ precise/universe i386 Packages
W: Failed to fetch mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt/dists/precise/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'main-updates/binary-i386/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have:

```
deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt precise main restricted universe multiverse
deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt precise-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt precise-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt precise-security main restricted universe multiverse
```

Upgrade your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file.